# how to solve database mysql overloaded

Tags: mysql

If the database is overloaded you'll get an increased number of queries running. Occasional spikes are OK for very short period of time. Too many active threads indicate that:

> 1. MySQL is taking too much time to process you requests.
> 2. You are continuously retrieving/updating large datasets.
>      Make sure that queries are tuned to use indexes. Execute SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST of find queries that are getting locked continuously. Try
>      isolating long running queries by enabling the slow query log.
>
> any help please

Comment: You should try to change mysql parameter value refer https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/

Comment: innodb_version is  5.5.59